# High level modelling of an existing application

Tags: visual-studio

I' asked about this before, but in a different context.  I Think I should have some sort of interconnected diagram, showing phyical components,  very loose layer diagram of some sort, or rather another component diagram, just grouping them.  Then some sort of process flow, much higher than e.g. a sequence diagram.  I think some of that will keep the PHB happy and let the real designers etc gust.  What do you all thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML component diagrams as discussed [here](http://rup.hops-fp6.org/process/modguide/md_cmpdm.htm) can be used to capture the structural information you describe. This kind of documentation is pretty useful for non-trivial systems, I don't think you should see it as just keeping the boss happy, irrespective of hair-shape.

Sequence diagrams may be helpful to capture some important scenarios.